# Unable to execute commands with Jsch shell channel

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I have a test case which connects to my app server using Jsch shell channel. I am able to execute commands using Jsch if I run my test case from test vm. But there is some situation that the test case will run in the app server and do ssh to itself with same credentials. My problem is here. In this case the commands are not executed by Jsch.

Code:

```
import com.google.common.io.Files;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created by prasantabiswas on 17/03/17.
 */
public class SSHManager
{
    private static Session session;
    private static Channel channel;
    private static ChannelSftp channelSftp;
    private static Logger log= LogManager.getLogger(SSHManager.class);
    private static HelperClass helperClass=HelperClass.getInstance();

    enum ChannelType
    {
        SHELL,
        SFTP
    }

    public static void openConnection(String remoteHost) throws JSchException,SecurityException
    {
        if(session == null || !session.isConnected())
        {
            String userName=helperClass.getSshUser();
            log.debug("Remote host: "+remoteHost);
            log.debug("SSH user: "+userName);
            if(helperClass.getSshAuthMode().equalsIgnoreCase("key"))
            {
                String key=helperClass.getSshKey();
                log.debug("SSH key: "+key);
                session=connectWithKey(remoteHost,userName,key);
            }
            else if(helperClass.getSshAuthMode().equalsIgnoreCase("password"))
            {
                String password=helperClass.getSshPassword();
                log.debug("SSH password: "+password);
                session=connectWithPassword(remoteHost,userName,password);
            }
            else
            {
                String password=helperClass.getSshPassword();
                log.warn("No SSH authentication mode provided. It will try with the default mode that is with password: "+password);
                session=connectWithPassword(remoteHost,userName,password);
            }
        }
        else
            log.warn("Session already connected. Disconnect first for new session.");
    }

    private static Session connectWithPassword(String hostname,String username,String password) throws JSchException,SecurityException
    {
        JSch jSch = new JSch();
        Session _session = jSch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        _session.setConfig(config);
        _session.setPassword(password);

        log.info("Connecting SSH to " + hostname + " - Please wait for few seconds... ");
        _session.connect();
        log.info("Connected!");
        return _session;

    }

    private static Session connectWithKey(String hostname,String username,String key) throws JSchException,SecurityException
    {
        JSch jSch = new JSch();
        log.debug("Key file path: "+key);
        jSch.addIdentity(key);
        Session _session = jSch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        _session.setConfig(config);

        log.info("Connecting SSH to " + hostname + " - Please wait for few seconds... ");
        _session.connect();
        log.info("Connected!");
        return _session;
    }

    private static void createChannel(ChannelType channelType)
    {
        if(channel == null || !channel.isConnected()){
            try
            {
                if(channelType==ChannelType.SHELL)
                {
                    channel = session.openChannel("shell");
                    log.info("Shell channel created!");
                }
                else if(channelType==ChannelType.SFTP)
                {
                    channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
                    log.info("SFTP channel created!");
                }
                else
                    throw new JSchException("Invalid channel type");
                channel.connect();

            }
            catch(JSchException e)
            {
                log.error("Error while opening channel: "+ e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String executeCommand(List<String> commands,String remoteHost) throws JSchException,IOException
    {

        log.info("Opening SSH session...");
        openConnection(remoteHost);
        log.info("Creating shell channel...");
        createChannel(ChannelType.SHELL);

        log.info("Sending commands...");
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());

        out.println("#!/bin/bash");
        for(String command : commands){
            out.println(command);
        }
        out.println("exit");
        out.flush();
        String output=getChannelOutput(channel);
        log.info("Finished sending commands!");
        log.info("Closing session...");
        close();
        log.info("Returning execution output...");
        return output;
    }

    public static void copyFileToRemoteHost(String sourcePath,String destinationPath,String remoteHost) throws SftpException, IOException, JSchException
    {
        log.info("Opening SSH session...");
        openConnection(remoteHost);
        log.info("Creating SFTP channel...");
        createChannel(ChannelType.SFTP);
        log.info("Copying file to remote host: "+remoteHost+" from "+sourcePath+" to "+destinationPath);
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(destinationPath);
        File sourceFile = new File(sourcePath);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(sourceFile), sourceFile.getName(),channelSftp.OVERWRITE);
        log.info("File transfer complete.");
        log.info("Closing session...");
        close();
    }

    public static void removeFileFromRemoteHost(String targetPath,String remoteHost) throws JSchException, SftpException, IOException
    {
        log.info("Opening SSH session...");
        openConnection(remoteHost);
        log.info("Creating SFTP channel...");
        createChannel(ChannelType.SFTP);
        log.info("Removing file from remote host: "+remoteHost+" at "+targetPath);
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.rm(targetPath);
        log.info("File removed");
        log.info("Closing session...");
        close();
    }

    private static String getChannelOutput(Channel channel) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        String line = "";
        Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        int minuteBefore=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int minuteAfter=0;
        while (true)
        {
            while (in.available() > 0)
            {
                int i = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                line += "\n" + new String(buffer, 0, i);
            }

            if(line.contains("logout"))
            {
                break;
            }

            if (channel.isClosed())
            {
                break;
            }
            calendar.setTime(new Date());
            minuteAfter=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            if(minuteAfter-minuteBefore>=3)
                break;

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        return line;
    }

    public static void close()
    {
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        log.info("Disconnected channel and session");
    }

}
```

I am using the above class to execute commands on remote host. This is working fine but when I am running it in my local machine with the remoteHost parameter being the localhost, the commands are not getting executed. However it successfully logs in which I can see in the log but cannot execute the commands which are sent throug print stream. It is stuck for sometime after "Sending commands..." and then return the log which only shows the command prompt not all the commands.

Suppose my ssh username is root and I am sending two commands : su - admin, txe restart and the remote host and the host I am running the test is same that is my localhost. I should get output like

```
#!/bin/bash
su - admin
txe restart
exit
Last login: Thu Apr 13 23:17:10 2017 from 10.10.4.46
[root@platform15 ~]# #!/bin/bash
[root@platform15 ~]# su - admin
id: cannot find name for group ID 491000000
admin@platform15(ERS):~> txe restart

Stopping txe...
.
.
OK

Starting txe...OK (PID: 13083)
admin@platform15(ERS):~> exit
logout
```

But I get this

```
Last login: Thu Apr 13 23:34:42 2017 from 10.10.4.27
[root@platform15 ~]#
```

This is only happening when I am running the test in localhost with remoteHost set to localhost. Otherwise it is working fine is remoteHost is set to some other host.

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your relevant source code. Describe in detail what happens when you run it. Include any error messages or exceptions that you get.

Comment: I have added code and explained as you requested.

Comment: *"run my test case from test vm"* - So you run the code on VM, but you connect to the same server as in the test, when it does not work? Or do you connect elsewhere?

Comment: Show us [mcve], not that zillions of lines of code, most of which is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: `out.println("#!/bin/bash");` - That's nonsense. The `#` denotes a comment - That code does nothing at all!

Comment: Does the `su - admin` work, when you connect to the same server using a standalone SSH client? Show us!